# Can we use multiple regression for a binary classification problem?

Tags: regression, classification, multiple-regression, model

I was recently asked a question by my colleague: Can we use multiple LINEAR regression for a binary classification problem?

Will the regression model be equally good as a classification model or it is not advisable at all to use multiple regression for a classification problem.

The dependent variable(y) is 0 or 1 and the model used is multiple linear regression. Is it correct to do so?

Comment: Ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: yes OLS was used. He was asked this question in an interview and he was supposed to point out the mistakes in the data problem.

Comment: See also [Logistic vs. OLS](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/95584/17230), which doesn't focus narrowly on performance as a classifier.